# Manage an email address with django / python / pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, email, django-allauth, pythonanywhere

I'm looking to host my django app and am currently hosting free on pythonanywhere.com. The django app uses all-auth which requires SMTP emailing.

I'm porting hosting to my own domain name, and with that want to start using an email @mywebsite.com.

How can I A) create and B) manage my @mywebsite.com inbox?

A) Am I able to do this through python anywhere?

B) Is there a neat django extension for this (e.g. a webmail client). All I know is to use the following settings for gmail:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'gmail password'
```

My domain-register is asking a ridiculous amount per mailbox (£35) so I'm not sure what my options are.

Comment: Probably just use google apps for managing the inbox. You can use your custom domain there. There are of course other options with email hosting but you would have to set up and maintain your own email servers otherwise which is easy to mess up.
Depending on your use case, you could use a service like postmark, mailgun, etc..

Comment: +1 for using Google Apps for email -- SMTP setup is hard!  It should work fine with PythonAnywhere for hosting.